# Q: What should I do if suitable Professor for my thesis research is completely booked?

Tags: thesis, masters, advisor

I plan to make Master Thesis with the topic around Energy Storage System and PV, unfortunately the suitable Professor in electric power system does not have time to be my advisor.

I will use Matlab as modelling tools. Should I go find the professor with expertise in Matlab and Math Modelling instead?

Or should I change my topic instead?

Comment: I decide to ask My Matlab Professor as Supervisor and have the Prof. in the institute as my secondary supervisor. Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 2):

You might try to convince the Professor's best student to supervise you. (Formally, the Professor might need to be listed as your supervisor, but the student will be your supervisor informally.)

Answer (score 1):

You can consider different professors, and ask this one if he is prepared to be an associate or supporting supervisor.

You may also consider a different institution, but you have not made your situation clear.

Answer (score 1):

Both the student and the advisor have to agree on a thesis topic.

You certainly can go talk to this other professor, tell them what you have in mind, and ask if they are willing to be your advisor on it.  They might say yes, they might say no.

They might also say yes, but with the caveat that they don't know very much about the engineering aspects of your work, and that you will be on your own should you need help with any of that material.  If so, then there's a risk that down the road, you might get stuck, or spend a lot of time working on something that turns out to be unworkable.  If it can't be resolved, you might have to start completely from scratch with a different topic, or you might run into time limits and have to leave without a degree.

So it's generally safer to choose an advisor / topic such that the advisor really is an expert on the topic.  However, you do have to balance that against your own interests.